# How would you store and access data in Android app?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making a dictionary app and need to store and access my data from the app. My goal is to make a completely offline dictionary.

I have all the data needed in JSON format (the file is about 9 MB), so I can convert it into any other format or even into sqlite database.
I try to dig some guides, but it appears to me that Android apps use sqlite only for user data. But I know that there are plenty of other offline dictionaries.

How do they store words and translations internally in the app? And what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the amount of data you need to store, SqlLite is the best option. Sqlite has a wide array of applications in Android apps; their scope is not limited to storing user data. The next best option would be to save the Json in a text file. You can then load the Json data in memory (when the app starts) and transform that to a dictionary structure with the JSON parsers. 
Downside of JSON: You need to load your entire stored JSON in memory before parsing it. With 9MB, its not a good idea.
SQLite is the best option if you do not want your 'entire' dictionary in memory at all times and need values only on a look up basis. You also get the full functionality of basic SQL statements with SQLite. Also, there is a lot of SQLite help online; choosing tried and tested technology is always good.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the developers website: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html